# Adding a custom Java script to Qliksense

Tags: javascript, qliksense

I admit that I am a newbie in Web development. I am finding a way to freeze the header while keeping the horizontal and vertical scroll.

Currently, I am trying to configure the CSS and JS for my Qliksense extension.

However I meet an issue when trying to add the JS part into my JS file. Here is their instruction, but I don't understand
http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/2.2/Subsystems/Extensions/Content/extensions-load-resources.htm

Basically, I need to add the below JS to the file.

```
$('table').on('scroll', function () {
    $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
});
```

Can anyone help me this subject :(.

Comment: I am following this code fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/X2Kmd/1/

Comment: Here is the link to my extension
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3QM1KdonGXWC1GZTRaNzAxd0k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

in the js file right after `$element.html(html);` add:

```
$('table').on('scroll', function () {
  $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
});
```

In the css file remove the `overflow: auto;`:

```
.qv-object-horizontal_scroll_table div.qv-object-content-container {
  overflow: auto; <-- Need to be removed
}
```

Also in the css file add the css from the fiddle example:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
}
thead {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 140px;
}
td, th {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: dashed 1px lightblue;
}
```

After this the header row is not moving while scrolling. The result:

[image]

Also remove all the code that is under `//start adding customized function`. If you want to include external js/css file you need to use RequireJS. For more info about this take a look at this [Load local Javascrtip files](https://github.com/stefanwalther/qliksense-extension-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial/part-01/09-Loading-Resources.md#loading-local-javascript-files). In general take a look at the whole project/tutorial

Comment: Just let me know how it went :)

Comment: hi @Stefan, my apology for late reply. I did make some modification to my original extension. They can work perfectly with out adding additional JS. However I has some issues  with it in IE.  You can see my new extension via https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3QM1KdonGXcjdFNUdOOW9kU1U/view?usp=sharing